# How to served cached page when magento sends back frontend cookie

Tags: magento, cookies, frontend, varnish

I've managed to setup varnish and magento and they are working quite nicely together, however when magento sends back a frontend cookie, which is every page except the home page, it's not hitting the cache

Set-Cookie:frontend=lm45mabgrqphfuvbbdbjume127; expires=Fri, 14-Dec-2012 02:32:37 GMT; path=/;

Is there a way to either turn off the magento frontend cookie for users that aren't using the cart, or is there a rule I could put into the default.vcl file that would allow varnish to served a cache page regardless of this cookie ?

appreciate any help :)

Comment: Did you try http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html ? The solution to get your cache rate going is ESI for session specific areas and/or removing the set-cookie - not sure which was chosen for this product.

Comment: Yes, have used PageCache and followed the instructions to set it up.  ALso used the default_3.0.vcl file that was shipped with the install.. The only thing i'm doing different is running varnish on a different server, so my apache is still on port 80, while the varnish is running on port 80 on a different server.

Comment: Here is a link where it's working http://c2accessories.thebigdot.com Headers contain X-Cache:HIT but this link http://c2accessories.thebigdot.com/index.php you can see it isn't.   Headers X-Cache: MISS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you install the [PageCache powered by Varnish module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html) for Magento. This magento module includes a default.vcl (Varnish configuration file) that takes care of this. All cookies and other info are stripped until a user adds a product to his cart or logs in into his account. This will allow the page to be served from Varnish and the request will never reach apache.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I did however install PageCache, that's the method I followed to get it working.  However the only difference to the install instructions is that I"m running varnish on a different server.

Comment: After a lot more digging I found that if I commented out if (req.url ~ "^/(index)") { return (pass) } it works.  It's failing to cache on anything that has index.php in the URL.  I think another solution might be if I enable mod_rewrite on the server and don't use index.php in any of the URLs.  Probably a better solution to enable mod_rewrite.    However,  it is working now :)

Comment: Commenting out the the "^/(index)"  actually didn't work, because it was sometimes reporting that cookies weren't enabled when adding to the cart.

Comment: How are you testing whether Varnish is caching? (use 'varnishlog | grep -i url')

Comment: Looking in varnishlog and also have debug enabled so I could see X-Cache headers.  I enabled mod_rewrite, but there was still one time when it redirected a user to enable cookies page after they added to the cart, but then I cleared every cache and I haven't seen it again.  But I'm still not 100% certain the problem has gone away.